# Cassandra: Can't use 'NOT NULL' constraint while creating table

Tags: cassandra

I see many examples on here that create tables using the NOT NULL constraint. Ironically I can't seem to do the same.

This is the cql command I use :

```
CREATE TABLE activities_dev (activity_id  uuid ,actor_id bigint NOT NULL, actor_appid bigint NOT NULL, item_id text NOT NULL, verb text NOT NULL,viewer_id bigint NOT NULL,viewer_appid bigint NOT NULL, ts timestamp, PRIMARY KEY(activity_id,actor_id,actor_appid,item_id,verb));
```

but this is the error I get:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:62 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ')' (...activities_dev(activity_id uuid, actor_id integer [NOT] NULL...)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Quite simply, you are using syntax that does not exist in Cassandra.

Answer (score 7):

**In Cassandra NOT NULL keyword not supported.**

For primary key columns cassandra automatically handle that. If you try to insert null to any primary key value cassandra will throw exception

`Invalid null value in condition for column`

Comment: This is no longer true now that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3783 is resolved.

Comment: @JeffWidman The question indicate if it's possible to create table with not null attribute but on the other hand the jira issue is about insert/update null values.

Comment: Ah, true, my mistake! Additionally, the scope of that ticket is even smaller than it appears from the issue title, per the final comment: _This ticket contracted from its original scope and turned into just support for upserting a null actually performing a delete operation on the cell. There is currently no select support for indexed nulls, and given the design of Cassandra, is considered a difficult/prohibitive problem._

Answer (score 2):

Null column in Cassandra does not mean empty column.

Cassandra uses nulls for marking deleted columns : you can delete one or several columns of a row in Cassandra.

This timestamped marker called tombstone is used for data reconciliation locally and between nodes (Commitlog, memtables, SStables) and in replicated keyspaces prevents resurrection of data (see [this article](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) for example about replicated deleted).

In this context, it makes sense not to allow a 'NOT NULL' clause in CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE CQL syntax.

Alain

Comment: NOT NULL on a column is used to prevent garbage from getting in the database.  Surely Cassandra does not invite garbage.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if your modifying this Column to be as NOT NULL , check that all fields inside this column to have value.

Comment: I ain't modifying the column of already created table. I am creating this table, but can't because of the cited error.

Comment: a turn around suggestion , run the sql script without NOT NULL and then alter the table by adding NOT NULL for specified columns.

Comment: "then alter the table by adding NOT NULL for specified columns" yeah, that doesn't work in Cassandra.